# image won't load in p5.js

Tags: javascript, image, p5.js

I am trying to upload a image to one of my p5 files.
I tried it the way it is described in the p5 reference, but that does not work.
Then I tried to write the image in a separate function and run that function in `draw()`, but that does not work either.
I also tried to embed the JS file to a HTML file to display it in a browser, but again, that doesn't work.
I tried to locate the problem by using `console.log` and apparently, you can't get into the `preload` function.

I also checked that the image has the right name and it is in the same folder as the JS file.

This is the code snippet I tried to use:

```
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("hamster.jpg");
}

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
}
```

Comment: which browser you are using

Comment: do you get an console errors, sharing them would be helpful. also try adding "./" before your image path

Comment: @abhinavxeon I am using firefox!

Comment: @WaliWaqar the only error I get in the firefox console is "TypeError: this._renderer is undefined": I get no error in visual studio code. And I also tried your suggestion with the "./". Unfortunatly that did not work :( but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.

Check out this p5 project I've created with your code - maybe there's an issue with your project structure:
https://editor.p5js.org/LukeGarrigan/sketches/WS_5sauc2

Comment: thank you for your answer! Very good to know that the code is working fine elsewhere, now I can search for the problem on my PC/project structure. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

For guys as dumb as myself, :p
My image was loading just fine, with live server. but it was bigger than
the canvas, and transparent part of it, was the only part in the canvas
That's why I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is start a local server, you are probably just clicking the html file. To start a local server use this guide https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server

Comment: `p5.js` is a client-side JavaScript library. No need for a server at all to come up with a working example. The documentation you've linked consists of examples for a convenient development environment, bus there is even an example to work without a local webserver: “Setting up Browser Sync for Sublime Text (command line free option)”.

Comment: @feeela would't the local web server still be useful to async load assets such as images and avoid needing to get into any nitty gritty stuff (crossdomain / HTTPS / etc.) ? (even if the OP hardcodes the path as `"file:///hamster.jpg"` that will need to change when the project goes online anyway)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let img;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("hamster.jpg");
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(600,600);
}

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value.

Comment: Although this is a good suggestion, p5 should create a 100x100 canvas automatically, so this probably wouldn't solve the problem.